# Is it possible or not to display multiple google calendar of one gmail account at one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have four added calendar. I got the iframe from each of them and plug them in the HTML code. When I run the code, it displays four different calendar. How can I merge all four calendar iframe and display them as a one?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Merge multiple calendar</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
      <iframe
        src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=t%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York"
        style="border: 0"
        width="800"
        height="600"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      ></iframe>
    </p>

    <p>
      <iframe
        src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=tyh%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York"
        style="border: 0"
        width="800"
        height="600"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      ></iframe>
    </p>

    <p>
      <iframe
        src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=tle%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York"
        style="border: 0"
        width="800"
        height="600"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      ></iframe>
    </p>

    <p>
      <iframe
        src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=te%40gmail.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York"
        style="border: 0"
        width="800"
        height="600"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
      ></iframe>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the content on the calendars to be merged into one calendar?  If so, that's something you'll need to set up in the google calendar itself.

Comment: yes, I don't think new input info in calendars will display when you run the code.